# Javascript not working as intended

Tags: javascript, html

My javascript code doesnt seem to run when i use this codes to validate the radio button is clicked. Its suppose to dropdown the inputs when the card radio button is clicked and it is suppose to slide up the inputs when the paypal button is clicked.1st code javascript. 2nd code html.

```js
if (document.getElementById('paypal').checked) {
  //Paypal radio button is checked
  $(".input-fields").slideDown("slow");
} else if (document.getElementById('card').checked) {
  //Card radio button is checked
  $(".input-fields").slideUp("slow");
};
```

```html
<div class="panel-body">
  <h2 class="title">Checkout</h2>

  <div class="bar">
    <div class="step active"></div>
    <div class="step active"></div>
    <div class="step"></div>
    <div class="step"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="payment-method">
    <label for="card" class="method card">
        <div class="card-logos">
            <img src="img/visa_logo.png" />
            <img src="img/mastercard_logo.png" />
        </div>

        <div class="radio-input">
            <input id="card" type="radio" name="payment"> Pay $<%= total %> with credit card
        </div>
    </label>

    <label for="paypal" class="method paypal">
        <img src="img/paypal_logo.png" />
        <div class="radio-input">
            <input id="paypal" type="radio" name="payment"> Pay $<%= total %> with PayPal
        </div>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="input-fields">
    <div class="column-1">
      <label for="cardholder">Cardholder's Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="cardholder" />

      <div class="small-inputs">
        <div>
          <label for="date">Valid thru</label>
          <input type="text" id="date" placeholder="MM / YY" />
        </div>

        <div>
          <label for="verification">CVV / CVC *</label>
          <input type="password" id="verification" />
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="column-2">
      <label for="cardnumber">Card Number</label>
      <input type="password" id="cardnumber" />

      <span class="info">* CVV or CVC is the card security code, unique three digits number on the back of your card separate from its number.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you missed was to add the logic inside a function and add it to an event using `addEventListener()` for value change.

We use `document.getElementById()` to get both the input elements by `ID` and then add the event listener to fire on change of value.

```
document.getElementById("card").addEventListener("change", validate);
document.getElementById("paypal").addEventListener("change", validate);
```

```js
function validate() {
  if (document.getElementById('paypal').checked) {
    //Paypal radio button is checked
    $(".input-fields").slideDown("slow");
  } else if (document.getElementById('card').checked) {
    //Card radio button is checked
    $(".input-fields").slideUp("slow");
  };
}

document.getElementById("card").addEventListener("change", validate);
document.getElementById("paypal").addEventListener("change", validate);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body">
  <h2 class="title">Checkout</h2>

  <div class="bar">
    <div class="step active"></div>
    <div class="step active"></div>
    <div class="step"></div>
    <div class="step"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="payment-method">
    <label for="card" class="method card">
                        <div class="card-logos">
                            <img src="img/visa_logo.png" />
                            <img src="img/mastercard_logo.png" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="radio-input">
                            <input id="card" type="radio" name="payment"> Pay $<%= total %> with credit card
                        </div>
                    </label>

    <label for="paypal" class="method paypal">
                        <img src="img/paypal_logo.png" />
                        <div class="radio-input">
                            <input id="paypal" type="radio" name="payment"> Pay $<%= total %> with PayPal
                        </div>
                    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="input-fields">
    <div class="column-1">
      <label for="cardholder">Cardholder's Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="cardholder" />

      <div class="small-inputs">
        <div>
          <label for="date">Valid thru</label>
          <input type="text" id="date" placeholder="MM / YY" />
        </div>

        <div>
          <label for="verification">CVV / CVC *</label>
          <input type="password" id="verification" />
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="column-2">
      <label for="cardnumber">Card Number</label>
      <input type="password" id="cardnumber" />

      <span class="info">* CVV or CVC is the card security code, unique three digits number on the back of your card separate from its number.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**References:**

1. [Event Listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your javascript inside an event listener. For Example

```
$("input[name='payment']").click(function ()
        {
            if (document.getElementById('paypal').checked)
            {
                //Paypal radio button is checked
                $(".input-fields").slideDown("slow");
            }
            else if (document.getElementById('card').checked)
            {
                //Card radio button is checked
                $(".input-fields").slideUp("slow");
            }
            ;
        });
```

Comment: thank you so much! i just realised i need event listener to make the function working